# MSBuild builds target even though condition is false

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have an MSBuild project file that builds a target even though its Condition is false

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDir>$(ProjectDir)build\</BuildDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="MakeBuildDir" Condition="!Exists('($BuildDir)')">
  <MakeDir Directories="$(BuildDir)" />
</Target>
```

BuildDir does exist, and it runs this task anyway.

From the log file:

```
15:32:17.162     1>Target "MakeBuildDir: (TargetId:3)" in project "foo.vcxproj" (target "bar" depends on it):
                   Using "MakeDir" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
                   Task "MakeDir" (TaskId:4)
                   Done executing task "MakeDir". (TaskId:4)
15:32:17.162     1>Done building target "MakeBuildDir" in project "KB.vcxproj".: (TargetId:3)
15:32:17.162     1>Target "bar: (TargetId:4)" in project "foo.vcxproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
                   Skipping target "bar" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
```

This isn't a crucial problem for me, but if I do two immediate builds on my solution, I want the second one to show me that all 11 of my projects are up-to-date. Now it takes a few seconds then says 2 succeeded and 9 are up-to-date.

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. What's the detail code of make_hfile, mak_lfile and make_dfile target? You can share a simple project on the OneDrive, which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks @starain. In creating the smaller file to share to OneDrive, I found a typo in one of my Outputs files so that it was a filename that wasn't getting created. So now I changed the question to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. It works if I change the target line to

```
<Target Name="MakeBuildDir" Condition="!Exists('$(BuildDir)')">
```

(though it still shows as succeeding, not up-to-date....)